# Пропуск слов в предложении возможен?

Tags: рассогласование

"Но Белоруссия обязана и обеспечит свободный транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых на себя обязательств перед другими государствами, заявил президент Лукашенко".
Можно ли так оставить предложение или надо обязательно исправить на:
"Но Белоруссия обязана обеспечить свободный транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых на себя обязательств перед другими государствами, и обеспечит его, заявил президент Лукашенко".

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Добавить нужно, но лучше в начале (обязана обеспечить и обеспечит) - в риторике президентов обязанности и их выполнение не должны разноситься на несколько слов. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Но Белоруссия обязана и обеспечит свободный транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых на себя обязательств перед другими государствами, заявил президент Лукашенко".

О ляпах. 
 1. Если это прямая речь, то ляп - постановка кавычек и тире. См. Русск. яз., 5-й класс.
 2. Если №1 так, то менять нельзя ничего. Хотя...
 3. Этот парняга бзззззграмотный. Транзит не умеет быть свободным, тразит можно разрешить или запретить, а бывает он платный и бесплатный. Страна обязалась, она не кем-то обязана.
 По-русски и безграмотно.
 "Но Белоруссия обязана и обеспечит свободный транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых на себя обязательств перед другими государствами," - сказал президент Лука Шенко.
По-русски и грамотно.
Но Белоруссия обязалась и обеспечит транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых  обязательств перед другими государствами, сказал президент Лука Шенко.

## А что у вас люди слово Говорить не знают? Они всё Озвучивают (киноленты) и Заявляют о запоре газов в кишечнике. Слово Встречи ещё живут рядом со мной в США (Обамка был на встрече с Меркель), а у вас саммиты да саминьки, неподшиты стареньки! Чем в Америку ходить, лучше русский поучить.

Это уж точно прямая речь. Ежли очень хоцца парнягу подгримировать.
"Но Белоруссия обязалась обеспечить транзит товаров через свою территорию в рамках принятых обязательств перед другими государствами, и обеспечит его," сказал президент Лука Шенко". -- Постан. зпт. определяется здесь интонацией. Обязалась и обеспечит. А если это решительное отрицание сомнений, то зпт. нужна, но тире лучше передаст эмоцию.  По поводу себя: Лука Шенко надел на свои ноги свои штаны и пошёл своими ногами свободным транзитом через всю свою комнату в свой туалет, где он озвучил свои действия и завершил их нежным шорохом бумаги.